# What's the difference between validation rules with bail and without in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

[If any of this rules failed, it'll be stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG1pL.png)

[And it’s gonna be the same here, isn’t it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilSX5.png)

Comment: Please share code not image

Comment: Everything is clearly writen in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy Just check out the error message and you will find that only one validation condition is checked when "bail" is provided

```
//when "bail" is not provided
$request->validate([
   'foo' => 'required|min:5|in:er,err,erro,error'
]);
/*
#messages: array:1 [
    "foo" => array:2 [
         0 => "The foo must be at least 5 characters."
         1 => "The selected foo is invalid."
    ]
]
*/

//when "bail" is provided
$request->validate([
    'foo' => 'bail|required|min:5|in:er,err,erro,error'
]);

/*

#messages: array:1 [
    "foo" => array:1 [
        0 => "The foo must be at least 5 characters."
    ]
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

As per docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure:

> Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an
> attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the
> bail rule to the attribute.

Maybe it's useless for simple validation, but you may have a validation `closure` or a `unique` validation that you want to avoid if the first validation fails.

Let's say you have a validation like this

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'max:255|unique:posts'
]);
```

In case of not using `bail`, the `unique:posts` will be hitting your database looking for a unique post despite `max:255` validation failed.

Or having a closure validation:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => [
        'max:255', 
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', $value)->count();
            if ($posts > 0) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
     ],
]);
```

Imagine having 500K posts, and looking for a post with the same title despite `max:255` fails.